# Prioritize TabNine autosuggestion over Intelephense with Coc

Tags: plugin-coc

I am trying to configure [TabNine](https://tabnine.com/) and [Intelephense](https://intelephense.com/) with [coc](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim).

I like the autosuggestions offered by TabNine. But Intelephense plugin is enabled, I am seeing suggestions from only Intelephense and not TabNine (probably because Intelephense is much faster).

I want to use TabNine for autocompletion, but continue to use the other  features of Intelephense engine like validation, function signature overlay, go to definition etc.

How can I turn off the autocomplete feature of Intelephense, or prioritize TabNine over Intelephense?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do this by setting `intelephense.completionProvider.maxItems` to `0` in `coc-settings.json`